# DynamoDB Mapper query() limit

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there any size limit on the no of result returned using dynamodb mapper's query() function. Following the documentation, but it doesn't mention any limit.
[DynamoDB Mapper query()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#query-java.lang.Class-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no size limit. The DynamoDB mapper query API returns `PaginatedQueryList`. The data is loaded based on the [PaginationLoadingStrategy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy.html).

> By default, the mapper uses **LAZY_LOADING**. Paginated list is lazily loaded when possible, and all loaded results are kept in the memory.